# Global Average Pooling from Array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, scikit-image, keras-layer

I am using InceptionV3 Model from Keras for extracting feature. Lets say I have 1000 images and I got the last layer with shape `(1000, 8, 8, 2048)`. Which `1000` from data size and `(8, 8, 2048)` from last convolutional layer. How can I implement Global Average Pooling? I am expecting the shape is `(1000, 1, 1, 2048)`.

Comment: Can you post a minimal code so that I can take a look first?

Comment: @Nain I was trying to import from `skimage.measure import block_reduce` and doing `block_reduce(X_train_feature, (1, 8, 8, 1), np.mean)`. The result shape was as I expected. I'm not certain but I hope that is a GAP.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X.shape
    (1000, 8, 8, 2048)
>>> X_gap = np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, X, [1, 2])
>>> X_gap.shape
    (1000, 1, 1, 2048)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GlobalAveragePooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalaveragepooling2d) for average-pooling or [`GlobalMaxPooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling2d) for max-pooling:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(8, 8, 2048)))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.summary()
```

It squashes feature maps globally to one value, so the output shape is `(batch_size, 2048)`:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 8, 8, 2048)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 2048)              0         
=================================================================
```

If you wish to output specifically 4-rank tensor, simply apply [`K.expand_dims`](https://keras.io/backend/#expand_dims) to expand it to `(batch_size, 1, 1, 2048)`.